# Extract set bytes position from SIMD vector

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics

I run a bench of computations using SIMD intructions. These instructions return a vector of 16 bytes as result, named `compare`, with each byte being `0x00` or `0xff` :

```
             0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7       15   16
compare : 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xff 0x00 0x00 0x00 ... 0xff 0x00
```

Bytes set to `0xff` mean I need to run the function `do_operation(i)` *with i being the position of the byte*.

For instance, the above `compare` vector mean, I need to run this sequence of operations :

```
do_operation(4);
do_operation(15);
```

Here is the fastest solution I came up with until now :

```
for(...) {
        //
        // SIMD computations
        //
        __m128i compare = ... // Result of SIMD computations

        // Extract high and low quadwords for compare vector
        std::uint64_t cmp_low = (_mm_cvtsi128_si64(compare));
        std::uint64_t cmp_high = (_mm_extract_epi64(compare, 1));

        //  Process low quadword 
        if (cmp_low) {
            const std::uint64_t low_possible_positions = 0x0706050403020100;
            const std::uint64_t match_positions = _pext_u64(
                    low_possible_positions, cmp_low);
            const int match_count = _popcnt64(cmp_low) / 8;
            const std::uint8_t* match_pos_array =
                    reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(&match_positions);

            for (int i = 0; i < match_count; ++i) {
                do_operation(i);
            }
        }

        // Process high quadword (similarly)
        if (cmp_high) { 

            const std::uint64_t high_possible_positions = 0x0f0e0d0c0b0a0908;
            const std::uint64_t match_positions = _pext_u64(
                    high_possible_positions, cmp_high);
            const int match_count = _popcnt64(cmp_high) / 8;
            const std::uint8_t* match_pos_array =
                    reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(&match_positions);

            for(int i = 0; i < match_count; ++i) {
                do_operation(i);
            }
        }
}
```

I start with extracting the first and second 64 bits integers of the 128 bits vector (`cmp_low` and `cmp_high`). Then I use `popcount` to compute the number of bytes set to `0xff` (number of bits set to 1 divided by 8). Finally, I use `pext` to get positions, without zeros, like this :

```
0x0706050403020100
0x000000ff00ff0000
        |
      PEXT
        |
0x0000000000000402
```

I would like to find a **faster solution** to **extract the positions** of the bytes set to `0xff` in the `compare` vector. More precisely, the are very often only **0, 1 or 2 bytes set to `0xff` in the `compare` vector** and I would like to use this information to avoid some branches.

Comment: I use GCC 4.9.1 for now but I'm okay with other versions of GCC or Clang.

Comment: Why not have  `do_operation` use SIMD?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick outline of how you could reduce the number of tests:

- First use a function to project all the lsb or msb of each byte of your 128bit integer into a 16bit value (for instance, there's a *SSE2* assembly instruction for that on X86 cpus: `pmovmskb`, which is supported on Intel and MS compilers with the [`_mm_movemask_pi8`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dkktcf5(VS.100).aspx) intrinsic, and gcc has also an intrinsic: `__builtin_ia32_ppmovmskb128`, );
- Then split that value in 4 nibbles;
- define functions to handle each possible values of a nibble (from 0 to 15) and put these in an array;
- Finally call the function indexed by each nibble (with extra parameters to indicate which nibble in the 16bits it is).

Comment: It's a detail but GCC also has the _mm_movemask_pi8 intrinsic. I think I cannot afford a function call (do_operation is inlined), but I'm going to try a variant of this solution with a jump table/switch case statement.

Comment: I came back to edit my post to include the idea of a switch instead of a function table, and I see your comment :)

Comment: You can loop over the set bits.  Find its position with `__builtin_ctz`, and clear it with `x &= (x-1)` (blsr), repeat until `x == 0`.  Oh, wim already posted that as an answer :P

Answer (score 5):

Since in your case very often only 0, 1 or 2 bytes are set to 0xff in the `compare` vector, a short
while-loop on the bitmask might be more efficient than a solution based on the `pext` 
instruction. See also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41958528/2439725) on a similar question.

```
/*
gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -mavx2 -march=broadwell esbsimd.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int do_operation(int i){           /* some arbitrary do_operation() */
   printf("i = %d\n",i);
   return 0;
}

int main(){

   __m128i compare = _mm_set_epi8(0xFF,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0xFF, 0,0,0,0);   /* Take some randon value for compare */
   int           k = _mm_movemask_epi8(compare);

   while (k){
      int i=_tzcnt_u32(k);                                /* Count the number of trailing zero bits in k.  BMI1 instruction set, Haswell or newer. */
      do_operation(i);
      k=_blsr_u32(k);                                     /* Clear the lowest set bit in k.                                                        */
   }
   return 0;
}

/* 
Output:

i = 4
i = 15

*/
```

Comment: You can write this as `__builtin_ctz` and `k &= k-1` so it can compile to BSF and plain instructions (only requiring SSE2), but it can still optimize to tzcnt and/or BLSR depending on target options.  Compilers do know about `blsr` as a peephole for that expression.